# ImportError No module named pygal keep showing

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, pygal

**Problem** : trying to show histogram using pygal , but error (*No module named pygal*) keeps showing

**Environment** : python 3.9.6 , Spyder 5.0.5 , pygal 1.7 , Windows 10

**How I've done:**

- I've installed pygal with pip in windows terminal

  `python -m pip install --user pygal`
- in the file I wanna run, I `import pygal` and `pygal.Bar()` to make histogram (full version of code is below.)
- Error "No module named pygal" shows

**What I've tried to solve this**

- 1. It seems python installed separately in spyder(anaconda) so I've changed the python PATH to python 3.9 which I've installed pygal.
     **->** now the console says
     *An error ocurred while starting the kernel
     Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 2.0.1 and < 2.1.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.*
     and I've put the code `conda install spyder‑kernels=2.0` but still can't run the code
- 2. I've upgraded the pygal to 2.2.3 but nothing has changed. Still can't run or the error shows.
- 3. I've reinstalled pip and pygal , and that doesn't work. I've reset the Spyder setting and that doesn't work. So, I've reinstalled the whole anaconda package. doesn't work.

**The only way left** :
pygal documentation says ***it's available only for python 2.7 , 3.2 , 3.3 , 3.4 , 3.5*.**
So, before I install the python 3.5 and run with it, I want to know is there anything I can do with python 3.9 to solve.

I don't think the code below has the main cause for this. I think the python version pygal supports or Spyder(anaconda) install its own python separately has the reason.
I've searched everything for this, and tried all of it.
Thank you for your time.

```
import pygal
from die import Die

# Create a D6.
die = Die()

# Make some rolls , and store results in a list.
results = []
for roll_num in range(1000):
    result = die.roll()
    results.append(result)

# Analyze the results.
frequencies = []
for value in range(1 , die.num_sides + 1):
    frequency = results.count(value)
    frequencies.append(frequency)

# Visualize the results.
hist = pygal.Bar()

hist.title = "Results of rolling one D6 1000 times."
hist.x_labels = ['1' , '2' ,'3' , '4' , '5' , '6']
hist.x_tile = "Result"
hist.y_title = "Frequency of Result"

hist.add('D6' , frequencies)
hist.render_to_file('die_visual.svg')

print(frequencies)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy histogram ([example](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html)) instead of changing to another version of Python